# WSL2 not accessible through Windows, but works fine through terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am running Ubuntu through WSL2 with no real problems until today. As I was coding in my Jupyter notbook (server running in WSL2, accessed through Firefox on Windows), I started to get strange errors, and realised that my Ubuntu terminal windows had all closed. I don't know if I misclicked and closed them, or if they terminated themselves.

I re-opened a terminal and launched the Jupyter server again, and it worked but had some strange behaviour. It looked as though it basically gave up while running scripts. It would be running a chunk of code, with the `[*]` and showing output underneath, and then with no apparent reason it would stop running. In the terminal window running the server, it would tell me that the kernel had restarted, but there was no error message or any further explanation.

After restarting my PC, Jupyter now seems to be working fine, and I can use the Ubuntu system normally through a terminal.

However, now I cannot access the files on the WSL2 mount through Windows at all (it seems). I've tried opening a folder in Windows Explorer, which just loads eternally without responding, and opening a file in Excel, which it fails to do (with no error message, it just doesn't load). Trying to browse through my files in the Excel "open file" browser also does not work, it produces the same behaviour as for the Windows file explorer.

I have tried restarting my PC as well as forcing the wsl shutdown through Windows Powershell, but the problem persists. What is happening? And if it's still unclear, what error logs should I look for to start to solve this problem?

---

Additional information:

Here is the output of some commands for additional information:

```
PS C:\Users\my.name> wsl --list --verbose
NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
```

```
(15:30) my@name:~$ dmesg | grep 9p
[    0.482852] 9p: Installing v9fs 9p2000 file system support
[    0.482862] FS-Cache: Netfs '9p' registered for caching
[    0.524632] 9pnet: Installing 9P2000 support
```

I do not have a `/etc/wsl.conf` file. Here are all the `.conf` files in my `/etc`:

```
muthur@RIT-callum:/etc$ ls *conf
adduser.conf          debconf.conf  e2scrub.conf  gai.conf     host.conf        ld.so.conf     logrotate.conf  mke2fs.conf     nsswitch.conf     overlayroot.local.conf  popularity-contest.conf  rsyslog.conf   sos.conf     ucf.conf       ca-certificates.conf  deluser.conf  fuse.conf     hdparm.conf  kernel-img.conf  libaudit.conf  ltrace.conf     multipath.conf  overlayroot.conf  pam.conf                resolv.conf              sensors3.conf  sysctl.conf  xattr.conf
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> dir .\p9np.dll
Répertoire : C:\Windows\system32
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        04/01/2021     15:59         107048 p9np.dll


PS C:\Windows\system32> reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider /s
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder
ProviderOrder    REG_SZ    P9NP,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order
ProviderOrder    REG_SZ    P9NP,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider
LanmanWorkstation    REG_DWORD    0x7d0
RDPNP    REG_DWORD    0x3e8
webclient    REG_DWORD    0xbb8
P9NP    REG_DWORD    0x1f4

PS C:\Windows\system32> reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\p9np /s
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\p9np
Description    REG_EXPAND_SZ    @%systemroot%\system32\p9np.dll,-101
DisplayName    REG_EXPAND_SZ    @%systemroot%\system32\p9np.dll,-100
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\p9np\NetworkProvider
DeviceName    REG_SZ    \Device\P9Rdr
DisplayName    REG_EXPAND_SZ    @%systemroot%\system32\p9np.dll,-100
Name    REG_SZ    Plan 9 Network Provider
ProviderPath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %SystemRoot%\System32\p9np.dll
TriggerStartCompleteNotification    REG_BINARY    7510BCA3541EC641
TriggerStartNotification    REG_BINARY    7508BCA3541EC641
TriggerStartPrefix    REG_SZ    wsl$

PS C:\Windows\system32> reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\p9rdr /s
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\p9rdr
DependOnService    REG_MULTI_SZ    RDBSS
Description    REG_SZ    @%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\p9rdr.sys,-101
DisplayName    REG_SZ    @%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\p9rdr.sys,-100
ErrorControl    REG_DWORD    0x1
ImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    System32\drivers\p9rdr.sys
Start    REG_DWORD    0x3
Type    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

---

So uh... the weirdest thing happened: the problem resolved itself?

I can now access my Ubuntu files with no problem through Windows Explorer and Excel and such. I didn't really "do" anything apart from restart my PC a few times. The one thing I did differently was instead of double clicking on the folders listed in the "quick access" tab of the Explorer (which caused it to load indefinitely), I manually typed `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` into the address bar at the top. And then it worked.

I'll leave the question open in case the issue resurfaces, and so that other people can still add their input on what may have happened.

Comment: We need more information, `wsl --list --verbose`, is the first thing that would be required.

Comment: @Ramhound in windows powershell, I assume? I'll post that

Comment: How about `Get-VM | wsl grep "Ubuntu"` and `dmesg |grep 9p` in their respective shells

Comment: @Ramhound Powershell is telling me that `Get-VM` is not recognised. Should I install it, or is it specific to one type of VM?

Comment: What about the other command? [Get-VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vm?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: @Ramhound posted the output of `dmesg`. Get-VM outputs nothing.

Comment: [So the dmesg output is correct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting), so everything should be working, have you checked the Github project to see if there are any similar reported issues?

Comment: Why is your distribution name `Ubuntu` rather than `Ubuntu 20.04` or similar? How have you installed Ubuntu, or have you renamed the distribution? Please add `/etc/wsl.conf` to your post, and also the output of [these commands](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4027#issuecomment-495812634). Try also running `Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service` from PowerShell that is Run as administrator.

Comment: @harrymc Fairly sure the distro name assigned comes from which version is installed from the Store.  There are three "version" - "Ubuntu" (which always installs the latest, currently 20.04), "Ubuntu 20.04" (to "force" the version to 20.04), and "Ubuntu 18.04".  Also, good idea on the Restart-Service, but I can't imagine that doing anything that a full PC reboot (which the OP says they did) wouldn't accomplish.  This one's bugging me ...

Comment: @Whitehot I kept reading that second paragraph as being part of your problem, but the third paragraph seems to say that you are no longer having that problem, right?  I made an edit to the question, but feel free to do a "rollback" on the edit if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @harrymc iirc I installed it following this guide https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/wsl/install-win10 , which is in french. Désolé. Updated the question with those commands, and I'll try `Restart-Service` when I get the chance.